# Run composer installed drupal from root (/) and not /web directory

Tags: composer

How do I run a composer-installed Drupal site from / instead of /web?

The default install with `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project ./` will install Drupal in the /web directory. So when the site is uploaded to a host, the actual website root will be [www.example.com/web](http://www.example.com/web). In most cases, the desired path to run the website is [www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/).

I have managed to do this, like this. And actually, I am asking if this is the definite correct way. (Clearly, I used my domain, not example.com.)

I have created a *.htaccess* file in the root with the following content.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [L]
```

I have uncommented the `RewriteBase` directive.

```
RewriteBase /web
```

I have added these lines in the *web/sites/default/settings.php* file.

```php
if (isset($GLOBALS['request']) and
  '/web/index.php' === $GLOBALS['request']->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME')) {
  $GLOBALS['request']->server->set('SCRIPT_NAME', '/index.php');
}
```

I have also uncommented these lines in the *web/sites/default/settings.php* file to cover the trusted hosts issue.

```php
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [
  '^example\.com$',
  '^.+\.example\.com$',
];
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: These questions seem similar: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294935/recommended-project-installs-drupal-into-the-web-subdirectory-but-hosting-so, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238550/how-to-remove-subdir-from-base-url-after-installing-site-with-composer-on-a-shar?rq=1, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260337/how-do-i-remove-web-from-the-url?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yeap...[This answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238550/how-to-remove-subdir-from-base-url-after-installing-site-with-composer-on-a-shar?rq=1) is pretty close where I am. But again even the poster of that answer is not sure about it. Really frustrating to be honest trying to achieve something so simple and critical.

Comment: The recommended-project is essentially this one file: https://github.com/drupal/recommended-project/blob/9.5.x/composer.json. Once used to set up a site initially, it is never updated without your knowledge. You can edit it as needed after that.

Comment: So the correct way is to edit the paths in the composer.json after the installation?

Comment: Doesn't this pretty much cover exactly what you're asking for? https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/manage-dependencies#s-to-do-a-modified-install

Comment: You can follow the instruction from this page: https://blogs.jamesrome.net/installingDrupal8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*web* is assumed to be the server document root directory. In some cases, the server document root directory is a different one, for example *public_html*.

You could either change the server settings to make the server use *web* as server document root directory, or change the commands executed, if you cannot do that.

As reported in [Using Composer to Install Drupal and Manage Dependencies / To do a modified install](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/manage-dependencies#s-to-do-a-modified-install), instead of running `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project ./`, you need to:

- Run `cd <directory containing the server document root directory>`
- Run `composer create-project --no-install drupal/recommended-project ./`
- Change any reference to *web* found in the *composer.json* file with the server document root directory
- Run `composer install`

For example, with the Linux distribution I am using (Endeavour OS), the default server documentation directory (indicated by `httpd -S` as *Main DocumentRoot*) is /srv/http. To install Drupal in that directory, I would execute the following commands.

```bash
cd /srv
composer create-project --no-install drupal/recommended-project ./
```

After, I would edit the *composer.json* file to change any occurrence of *web* with *http*. In the case the directory *web* is indicated with its full path, I would change that accordingly. Then, I would run `composer install`.

Comment: You are correct but there's an issue with this method. [See here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/315154/composer-modified-installation-with-changed-web-reference-in-composer-json-fail)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct way?

No, it's not and it's a security risk.

Ideally, you would configure the web server to point the domain `www.example.com` to the sub-folder `/var/www/my-project/web` (or any other subfolder you have configured in composer.json). All web servers support this. If it's your own server configure a virtual host, hosting providers usually have a nice UI to manage these things.

Only if this is not possible use the legacy project:

```
composer create-project drupal/legacy-project .
```

It's important to use this project and not try to move the web folder yourself to root, because this project has extra protection for the vendor folder now being exposed in `www.example.com/vendor`.

This is the line that needs to be present in composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "^10.0"
```

See https://github.com/drupal/legacy-project/blob/10.0.5/composer.json#L22

To be clear, the problem here is not renaming the subfolder, for example from /web to /public_html. It's about the original question, running Drupal without a subfolder from the web server's root.