# Composer modified installation with changed /web reference in composer.json fails

Tags: installation, 10

Based on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/315085/run-composer-installed-drupal-from-root-and-not-web-directory/).

I am running a modified composer installation.

```
composer create-project --no-install drupal/recommended-project ./
```

I am changing "web" in the composer.json like so:

```
{
"name": "drupal/recommended-project",
"description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with a relocated document root",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
"support": {
    "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
    "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
],
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.9",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.5",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.5",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.5"
},
"conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
        "composer/installers": true,
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
        "drupal/core-project-message": true,
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "locations": {
            "web-root": "/"
        }
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "/core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "/libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ],
        "/modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
        "/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-profile"
        ],
        "/themes/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-theme"
        ]
    },
    "drupal-core-project-message": {
        "include-keys": [
            "homepage",
            "support"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "",
            "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
            "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/installing-drupal",
            "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
            "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
            "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
            "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
            "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
            "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
        ]
    }
}
}
```

And when I run `composer install`

I get errors similar to this:

```
file_put_contents(//.csslintrc): failed to open stream: Read-only file system
```

NOTE: Running a normal composer installation, installs normally with no issues:

```
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project ./
```

I have also tried `composer update` after the changes in composer.json, but I get the same issue.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use the recommended project to remove the subfolder. Even if you get it working this is a security risk. See my answer to the previous question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/315089/47547

Comment: `web-root` is not /, but the server document root directory as set in the server configuration. Neither the answers given in the previous question said to use / as server document root directory.

Comment: The suggestion in my answer is to use a different composer project. This has the desired result: https://github.com/drupal/legacy-project/blob/10.0.5/composer.json#L43